# what is minimum number of operations required to sort an array if:-

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

In each operation we can either push an element to the end of the array or at the beginning of it
for example an array  3 2 5 1 4 6 would take 4 steps.
after first operation 2 3 5 1 4 6
after second operation 1 2 3 5 4 6
after third operation 2 3 1 4 6 5
after fourth operation 1 2 3 4 5 6

Comment: What if the array is already sorted? Also, is there a programming question here?

Comment: if the array is already sorted then obviously 0 operations are required,and yes it's a programming question. i would not have asked if i hadn't already tried a lot, it's relatively easy i presume but it's just not clicking with me at the moment, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

I think in the best case, the array is already sorted - 0 operations needed.
In the worst case, its sorted already, but in the opposite order (eg 6 5 4 3 2 1), you gonna need number of elements-1 operations.

Comment: no, i don't think so pal. i mean look at the example in the question body it's not as straight forward as you might have thought .

Comment: Do you have a counter example which needs more than elements-1 operations?

Comment: i've asked MINIMUM no. of operations required not the maximum